# Unable to uninstall older version of "matplotlib" using conda

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, conda, uninstallation

Disclaimer: I am not techie / Python developer but trying to learn it & leverage for EDA in Jupyter notebook for ML problems

Team -  Find the extract of the conda uninstall error message though it displays multiple matplotlib version installed. Either I run into package not available (if I uninstall the latest version 3.3.2) or post installation I am unable to use it Jupyter notebook.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda search matplotlib

Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
matplotlib                     1.1.1      np16py27_2  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.2.0      np16py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.2.0      np16py27_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.2.0      np17py27_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.2.1      np17py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.2.1      np17py27_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.3.0      np17py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.3.1      np17py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.3.1      np17py27_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.3.1      np18py27_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.3.1      np18py27_2  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.0      np18py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.0      np19py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.1      np19py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.2      np19py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.3     np110py27_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.3     np110py27_2  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.3     np110py27_3  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.3      np19py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.3      np19py27_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.4.3      np19py27_3  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.5.0     np110py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.5.1     np110py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.5.1     np111py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.5.3     np111py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.5.3     np111py27_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     1.5.3     np111py36_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.0     np111py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.0     np111py36_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.0     np112py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.0     np112py36_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.1     np111py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.1     np111py36_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.1     np112py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.1     np112py36_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.2     np111py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.2     np111py36_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.2     np112py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.2     np112py36_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.2     np113py27_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.2     np113py36_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.2  py27hd2e917d_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.0.2  py36h58ba717_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.1.0  py27h86412ea_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.1.0  py36h11b4b9c_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.1.1  py27h3be7b3c_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.1.1  py36h2062329_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.1.2  py27ha51faf0_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.1.2  py36h016c42a_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.2.0  py27hf8772e1_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.2.0  py36h4dabdea_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.2.2  py27h8803d4e_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.2.2  py27h8803d4e_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.2.2  py36h153e9ff_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     2.2.2  py36h153e9ff_1  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     3.0.3          py36_0  repository/conda_gold_group
matplotlib                     3.3.2  py36h9f0ad1d_1  repository/conda_gold_group
```

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda uninstall matplotlib
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - matplotlib
```

Answer (score 2):

open your cmd and use command `conda remove package_name --yes` 
or if you are not into the environement use `conda remove -n Environment package_name --yes`

sources: 
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#removing-packages
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html

Answer (score 0):

> though it displays multiple matplotlib version installed

You are mistaken in what `conda search` does. It only shows you all the versions that you **can** install, i.e. which versions are available from the configured channels for your OS, it is somewhat equivalent to using the search function on anaconda.org .

The command you are thinking of is `conda list` ([docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html)), which shows you a list of packages that **are** installed currently.

So you probably have no matplotlib installed currently, since your uninstall command yields

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - matplotlib
```

Now you can simply install a version that you need, i.e. for 2.12, simply do

```
conda install matplotlib=2.12
```

or any other version that you might need